# DELETE FROM not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Related to Java and MySQL:
After I press the button and check my database, the row with ID 25 is still there. Why?

In QueryManager.java everything is set and working with the database.
This is in QueryManager.java:

```
public void removeGebruiker() {
        String query;
        query = "delete from gebruiker where gebruiker_ID = 25";
    }
```

In userPanel.java I can already add users to the database, but deleting does not work.
This is in userPanel.java:

```
private void removeUserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        WinkelApplication.getInstance().getQueryManager().removeGebruiker();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gebruiker is verwijderd", "Gebruiker", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: Where is the query execution code ?

Comment: Well from the looks of it all you have done is create a string with some SQL in it. You haven't actually run the SQL.

Comment: Why is the ID wrapped in quotes?

Comment: for testing purposes when  = 25 did not work. Already changed it

Comment: if your 'add' function works, copy it to 'delete', modify as necessary, test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just construct a `String` and never execute the query that it contains.

In here:

```
String query;
query = "delete from gebruiker where gebruiker_ID = '25'";
```

Make sure you actually execute the query.

If the code really uses this [QueryManager](http://outfit4you2.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3/outfit4you2/src/connectivity/QueryManager.java), you need to call `dbmanager.executeQuery(query);` I think (though I am new to this code).

Comment: how do you do that, by `query.execute();`?

Comment: @F4LLCON :probably I found the code you are using. I updated my answer with what I think should do for you.

Comment: @F4LLCON But does my code make any sense with yours? I mean I am not even sure I found the exact code to refer to. What happens if you add the line I suggest?

Comment: yes it does, found it, I just used the execution part of my addGebruiker, and it worked, strange because if you ask me, insertQuery is INSERTING something and execute is EXECUTING. Well that's not true.... This code worked: `dbmanager.insertQuery(query);`. Thanks

Comment: @F4LLCON I will suggest take a look at code where you adding the record to DB, Use it as reference to execute your delete sql.

Answer (score 3):

without quotes around 25

```
 delete from gebruiker where gebruiker_ID = 25
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to execute the query
try this link http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/execute-sql-query.shtml